# ORA-12170 Timeout error occured with sqlnet.log

Tags: oracle

I am getting error ORA-12170 while connecting from C# application to Oracle database. I searched and found somewhere that the error description can be found in sqlnet.log file. What I am pasting is the sqlnet.log content. How can I overcome this problem?

Fatal NI connect error 12170.

VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 08-JUN-2016 18:49:09
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12535
    TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 505
    TNS-00505: Operation timed out
    nt secondary err code: 60
    nt OS err code: 0
  Client address:

Answer (score 1):

> main err code: 12535

This only tells there is a time-out

> secondary err code: 12560

A quick look-up tells us this is "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error".

Have you started the Oracle service yet?

To check the Oracle services, you can use command line to run "`services.msc`", then locate the Oracle services and start them.